# Expresso Store - upload multiple discount codes to be used once

Tags: expresso-store, expresso

I want to generate a list of discount codes (any advice appreciated for doing this) which I can then use to offer free shipping across the site, valid up until a specific date.

What's the best way to go about creating these discounts? I'd prefer not to have to manually create hundreds of discounts all the same except for the discount code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the most basic way to do it yourself is probably using Navicat and Excel. Create one discount that matches how you want it work. Export the SQL table to your desktop as a CSV or XLS file. Open that in Excel and duplicate the rows adjusting the code column as you want to show differences. Then import those rows back into the database. You could do it other ways, but this would be the novice ways for those with little MySQL/Php experience.

Comment: Thanks Parscale. I've just looked into Navicat, after your suggestion and think I'll trial it. PhpMyAdmin gets a bit tedious sometimes and I like the idea of being able to manage all of my databases from one place.
Am I right in thinking there is only one table that will need editing, then?

Comment: You should only need to edit the `exp_store_discounts` table. As always when making changes in the DB directly make a backup first just in case.

Comment: This worked fine. I just used PhpMyAdmin and a CSV file.